# Selenium(Python) - How to get text after image tag

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, text, webdriverwait

```
<ul class="meta">
   <li class="user">
       <img class="classname" src="some url">
       givemetext               
   </li>
</ul>
```

How do I get the text **givemetext** with python selenium?

Answer (score 0):

In presented here XML "givemetext" text belongs to `<li class="user">`.
So, in order to retrieve this text you have to get that web element and extract it's text.
Something like:

```py
text_value = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//li[@class='user']").text
```

Still need to validate the selected locator is unique, no problem with wait / delay, the element is not inside iframe etc.

Comment: How do i do that? (Still need to validate the selected locator is unique, no problem with wait / delay, the element is not inside iframe etc.)

Comment: These are different issues. To validate the locator is unique you should use the F12 dev tools to see only 1 element on that page is matching that locator. As about waits / delays - I need to see all your code. Generally, after each loading / changing page you have to apply delays to let elements completely loaded before accessing them. Especially when you are going to extract their texts. Expected conditions are the best approach here. presence of iframes are also can be checked with dev tools...

Comment: @Andrei Great! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The text ***givemetext*** is a *text node* within it's ancestor `<li>`.

To print the text ***givemetext*** just after the `<image>` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.meta li.user").text)
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='meta']//li[@class='user'][./img[@class='classname' and @src='some url']]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.meta li.user"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='meta']//li[@class='user'][./img[@class='classname' and @src='some url']]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)